# How do you get a user's id from a Magento REST API token?

Tags: api, magento, rest, oauth, token

Following [these instructions](http://www.magentocommerce.com/api/rest/authentication/oauth_configuration.html#OAuthConfiguration-ViewingAuthorizedTokens), it's easy to see that Magento is associating the OAuth tokens with a user id after they're granted. Is there a way to programmatically recover the  user id, given the OAuth token?

Answer (score -1):

If helps, you can do it like this:

```
// Should be a collection of one element (or zero if nothing found)
$tokens = Mage::getModel('oauth/token')->getCollection()->addFilterById($tokenId);
foreach ($tokens as $token) {
    echo $token->getCustomerId();
}
```