# Get user's id from a Magento REST API session?

Tags: php, rest, magento

This is a followup question regarding this post:
[How do you get a user's id from a Magento REST API token?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18618079/how-do-you-get-a-users-id-from-a-magento-rest-api-token/29273470#29273470)

What should I assign to the **$tokenId** variable?

I tried the Consumer Key as well as the Access Token, but I do not seem to get the user ID

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure that I fully understand the question. But if you're trying to get the **API User's** ID during an API request, you'll want to go through the API session like so:

```
$apiUserId = Mage::getSingleton('api/session')->getUser()->getId();
```

Make sure to use `getSingleton` and not `getModel`. Otherwise, this should work from most any place, including event observers.

Answer (score 0):

Fetch the token's collection by the unique accessToken we have. The collection we'll get contains only one row as the accessToken is unique. Use the following code for the same:

```
$oauthCollection = Mage::getModel('oauth/token')->getCollection()->addFieldToFilter('token',$accessToken)->getFirstItem();
// $accessToken is the access token generated
```

The row in turn will hold the user Id for whom the token was generated which can be grabbed like:

```
echo $oauthCollection->getCustomerId(); //For customer type account
echo $oauthCollection->getAdminId(); //For Admin type account
//Only one of the above will hold the ID
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, it would be better to include some context, explaining how it works and when to use it. Code-only answers are not useful in the long run.

Comment: It was my first first answer, I've updated the answer accordingly. Thanks